# python code - Wants code to accept certain numbers

Tags: python-3.x

```
coins = input("enter x number of numbers separrated by comma's")
while True:
    if coins == 10, 20, 50, 100,:
        answer = sum(map(int,coins))
        print (answer)
        break
    else:
        print ('coins not accepted try again')
```

Want the program to only accept numbers 10 20 50 and 100 (if numbers valid must add them together otherwise reject numbers) this code rejects all numbers

Answer (score 1):

```
coins = input("enter x number of numbers separated by commas")
whitelist = set('10 20 50 100'.split())
while True:
    if all(coin in whitelist for coin in coins.split(',')):
        answer = sum(map(int,coins))
        print (answer)
        break
    else:
        print ('coins not accepted try again')
```

From the in-comment conversation with @adsmith, it seems that OP wants a filter. To that end, this might work better:

```
coins = input("enter x number of numbers separated by commas")
whitelist = set('10 20 50 100'.split())
answer = sum(int(coin) for coin in coins.split(',') if coin in whitelist)
print answer
```

Comment: Getting this error with this code: enter x number of numbers separrated by commas10, 20
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Documents and Settings/hollandk/My Documents/a453/adding with loop 1.py", line 4, in <module>
    if all(coins.split(',') in whitelist):
TypeError: unhashable type: 'list'
>>>

Comment: @user3395739: Oops! Sorry about that. It's fixed now

Comment: This may be even better if you did `coins = [int(coin) for coin in coins if coin in whitelist]` then ignore the `if all(...)` condition. That way it really does ignore entries outside of the whitelist, rather than just reject the entire entry (so `["10","20","foo","50"] == 80`), though you may want to check that the list is non-empty! :D

Comment: @adsmith: That's a filter, and it would definitely work the way you describe it. Ultimately, I suppose it depends on what OP wants for intended behavior

Comment: @inspectorG4dget I was implying from "Want the program to only accept numbers 10 20 50 and 100 (if numbers valid must add them together otherwise reject numbers)" he wanted the filter, rather than rejecting the entire input. You're right, though, it's definitely a question of "Well, what does the OP want to do?"

Answer (score 0):

You can try sanitizing your input as it's entered instead of cycling through afterwards. Maybe this:

```
coins = list()
whitelist = {"10","20","50","100"}

print("Enter any number of coins (10,20,50,100), or anything else to exit")
while True:
    in_ = input(">> ")
    if in_ in whitelist: coins.append(int(in_))
    else: break

# coins is now a list of all valid input, terminated with the first invalid input
answer = sum(coins)
```

Comment: I still cant get them to work - I want the user to input set coins and then the system to add them together and display total

Comment: @user3395739 Does the computer seize up? Do you get a BSOD? Do flying monkeys come out? Does it explode? How exactly does it "not work?"

Comment: doesnt add up the entries Enter any number of coins (10,20,50,100), or anything else to exit
>> 10
>> 20
>> 30
>>>

Comment: @user3395739 it does add up the entries, that's what `answer = sum(coins)` does. It doesn't DISPLAY that anywhere. I figure you can figure that part out, eh?